# AIC() for mgcv model

Tags: r, mgcv

I am creating a series of logistic regression models using mgcv and comparing them with AIC(). I have only four variables (socioeconomic class (Socio), sex, year of death (YOD), and age) for each individual and I am curious how these variables explain the likelihood of someone being buried with burial goods (N=c.12,000).

For one model, I ran the following:

```
model5 <- mgcv::gam(Commemorated ~ s(Age, k=5) + s(YOD, k=5) + Socio + Sex + 
              ti(Age,YOD, k=5) + s(Age, by=Socio, k=5) + s(YOD, by=Socio, k=5),
                        family=binomial(link='logit'), data=mydata, method='ML')
```

AIC(model5) was -1333.434. This was drastically different than I expected given models I had run previously. As a test, I ran the following:

```
model6 <- mgcv::gam(Commemorated ~ s(Age, k=6) + s(YOD, k=5) + Socio + Sex + 
              ti(Age,YOD, k=5) + s(Age, by=Socio, k=5) + s(YOD, by=Socio, k=5),
                        family=binomial(link='logit'), data=mydata, method='ML')
```

`gam.check()` for both models were fine. For the second model, I only shifted the k value of the first term up 1, which in my understanding should not have altered the AIC drastically but when I ran `AIC(model6)`, it was 6048.187, which is as expected given previous models I have run.

Other things I have looked at:

`model5$aic`: 6047.284

`model6$aic`: 6047.245

`logLik.gam(model5)`: -3005.652 (df=-3673.87)

`logLik.gam(model6)`: -3005.629 (df=18.46467)

So it would appear that for some reason, the degrees of freedom for model5 is drastically different than model6 for a reason I cannot explain. If anyone has any ideas on how to troubleshoot this problem further, it would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: As commented below, I have also altered model5 from `s(YOD, k=5)` to `ti(YOD,k=5)` and this 'fixes' the AIC() result. Running model5 without the term, Sex (which previous models have shown has little effect but I have left in because it is meaningful from a theoretical standpoint), also 'fixes' the AIC() result. So this problem is not specific to the term s(Age), the number of knots, or the smoothed terms in general.

Comment: I doubt that this can be answered without access to the data. Seeing multiple s-terms with Age makes me wonder if that is causing numerical anomalies. Appears to be a case of a fruitless pursuit of AIC improvements at the expense of interpretability.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I cannot provide access to the data and without having any clue what might cause this, I have not been able to reproduce it at all. I should also note that simply adjusting the term `s(YOD,k=5)` to `ti(YOD,k=5)` similarly 'fixes' the AIC() value when changing the number of knots in s(Age) back to 5 so I do not believe it is a problem specific to the Age term or the number of knots

Comment: WHat do the fitted smooth functions look like in both cases? I can think of some situations where a simple change to `k` for the global smooth of `Age` so that is can now fit a slightly wiggly smooth would then reduce the degrees of freedom needed for each of the `Age` by `Socio` smooths. You certainly should add `m=1` to each of your `by` smooths; having a smooth of the same variable in two terms can cause numerical problems, but changing the order of the penalty for the `by` smooths can help to reduce this as the penalties on the global and by smooths are forcing different behaviour

Comment: Hi, in terms of adding ```m=1``` to each ```by``` term, my understanding was that this would make the ```by``` term reflect the difference between it and the global smooth as represented by the first-order term. However, I am more interested in the differences between the socioeconomic classes. Perhaps this means I should drop the first order smooths? In regards to changing ```k```, the problem is resolved if I leave k the same and just drop the term ```Sex``` as well as leave ```k``` the same but change one smooth from s() to ti() so I do not believe it is specific to the ```k``` term